# SQL performance width versus depth

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a customers table that holds information about customer prefrences like if he wants to receive a newsletter and so on. If he/she wants to receive a newsletter, the value is stored in the column "customerNewsletter" and set to true. However I have a couple of these bit values and parameters that are in a column of there own. I store dates, true/false, integers and tekst like this for each customer.

I find that about 80% of my customers wants to receive a newsletter and that makes that 80% of the values is set to true. I now store a value for each customer set to false or true. What if I only should have to store the 20% set to false ??

There is a list of about 20 of these parameters that I could include as a column (they are now), but I was wondering if there is a better way.

So I create 3 tables to hold these parameter values, a param table holding the actual value, a paramsNames table, that holds the names of the values and a params table that connects the parameters to a customerID

```
SELECT 
customerParamsName as [Name],
customerParamText as [Text],
customerParamINT as [int],
customerParamsDateTime as [Date] 
FROM db14.customerParams
INNER JOIN db14.customerParam ON customerParamsChildID = customerParamID
INNER JOIN db14.customerParamsNames ON customerParamNameID = customerParamsNameID
```

This would give me

```
Name         Text         int   Date
Phonenumber  NULL   615164898   2013-09-20 00:00:00.000
```

Can anyone tell me if this is a good way to go, or are there more common ways of storing Multi-Type parameters more efficiently ?

---

### AFTER some MORE consideration

I have created 2 tables

customerParam

```
paramID  paramNameID  ParamParentID  paramChildID  paramText    paramINT  paramDate
INT      TINYINT      INT            INT           varchar(24)  INT       DATETIME
PRIMARY               INDEXED
```

customerParamNames

```
paramNameID    paramName
TINYINT        VARCHAR(24)
PRIMARY

          1    'FirstName'
          2    'LastName'
          3    'Email Address'
          4    'Phonenumber'
          5    etc..
```

Let's say I want to store the firstName and LastName

I create records in customerParam for both values ;

```
paramID  paramNameID  ParamParentID  paramChildID  paramText    paramINT     paramDate
17456              1                               'John'
17467              2                               'Doo'
17468              1            752         17456
17469              2            752         17467
```

As I expect more occurrences for the name ‘John’ I am storing it as an independent value, then joining it using the parentID/ChildID combination.

and for the phoneNumber

```
17470              4            752                             31615164899            
17471              5            752                'me@here.com'
```

The phonenumber is very explicit to this customer, I am using the parentID to join it straight to the customer. The same goes for the emailaddress.

At this time this solution looks like the way to go... I am also still looking at the xml approach but I don’t have a good understanding on how to use XQuery and xmlDocuments stored in a database. 
And It seems like a lot of overhead.

I will move forward with the solution above... until someone gives me a better one.

Example SQL

```
DECLARE @paramNames TABLE (paramNameID TINYINT, paramName varchar(24))

DECLARE @param TABLE (paramID INT, paramNameID TINYINT, paramParentID INT, paramChildID INT, paramText varchar(24), paramINT INT, paramDate datetime)

INSERT INTO @paramNames VALUES ( 1, 'firstname')
INSERT INTO @paramNames VALUES ( 2, 'lastname')
INSERT INTO @paramNames VALUES ( 3, 'emailaddress')
INSERT INTO @paramNames VALUES ( 4, 'phonenumber')

select * from @paramNames

INSERT INTO @param VALUES (1, 1, Null, Null, 'John' , Null, Null)
INSERT INTO @param VALUES (2, 2, Null, Null, 'Doo' , Null, Null)
INSERT INTO @param VALUES (3, 1, 752, 1, Null , Null, Null)
INSERT INTO @param VALUES (4, 2, 752, 2, Null , Null, Null)
INSERT INTO @param VALUES (5, 4, 752, Null, Null , 615164899, Null)
INSERT INTO @param VALUES (5, 3, 752, Null, 'me@here.com' , Null, Null)

select 
a.paramParentID, b.paramName, c.paramText, c.paramINT, c.paramDate
from @param a
inner join @paramNames b on a.paramNameID = b.paramNameID
inner join @param c on a.paramChildID = c.paramID
UNION ALL
select 
a.paramParentID, b.paramName, a.paramText, a.paramINT, a.paramDate
from @param a
inner join @paramNames b on a.paramNameID = b.paramNameID
WHERE paramParentID IS NOT NULL
AND paramChildID IS NULL
```

giving the result

```
paramParentID   paramName       paramText   paramINT    paramDate
752             firstname       John        NULL        NULL
752             lastname        Doo         NULL        NULL
752             phonenumber     NULL        615164899   NULL
752             emailaddress    me@here.com NULL        NULL
```

Comment: If you use `TINYINT` to store your true/false values that's one byte per value. Efficiency is about more than saving a byte here and a byte there. If you combine your booleans into one field you have the added complexity of unpacking them which will add to maintenance costs if nothing else. Make life easy - leave them as they are and look elsewhere for savings.

Comment: If you use BIT to store the bools you need one bit per bool (not one byte). Hard to beat that. Row overhead is at least 7 byte = 56 bits.

Comment: Unless there is some mitigating (highly irregular) scenario, your "after consideration" scenario sounds way too complicated.

Comment: @Max, can you give me an alternative to my "way to complicated" solution. Take in mind that I need to store about 30 properties on a single customers, ranging from dates, integers to strings and booleans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution is a variant of what is commonly known as [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) data model. This approach appears to be flexible. However, it essentially generates a schema within schema and is very slow to query as the number of attributes increases

If you're storing a lot of identical values, have a look at [columnstore indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx). They work well in scenarios where selectivity is low (lots of rows & only a small number of distinct values)

Comment: I now have a better understanding of the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) data model. The article describes exactly my problem and that there is no “out of the box” solution. EAV has its advantages, but can be slow when the amount of data increase. 

So I need to look out for a mix of relational and EAV data models. AS From SQL Server 2008 and up, storing NULL values does not take up any space and are not indexed. This would increase performance on the columnar data model.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this a little differently if you have performance and flexibility in mind.

```
USE Test;

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Customers 
                 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CustomerName NVARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE CustomersReceivingEmails
(
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID 
                 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers (CustomerID)
                 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    , EmailAddress NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_CustomersReceivingEmails 
                 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID, EmailAddress)
);

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('Max');
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('Mike');

INSERT INTO CustomersReceivingEmails (CustomerID, EmailAddress) 
        VALUES (1, 'us@them.com');
INSERT INTO CustomersReceivingEmails (CustomerID, EmailAddress) 
        VALUES (1, 'us@me.com');

/* ALL Customers */
SELECT * FROM Customers;

/* Only customers who wish to receive Emails, allows a given customer 
    to have multiple email addresses */
SELECT C.CustomerName, E.EmailAddress 
FROM Customers C 
    INNER JOIN CustomersReceivingEmails E ON C.CustomerID = E.CustomerID
ORDER BY C.CustomerName, E.EmailAddress;
```

The `SELECT` returns rows like this:

[image]

This allows the `Customers` table to contain all customers regardless of their preference for emails.

The `CustomersReceivingEmails` table has a foreign key to `Customers.CustomerID` for customers who want to receive emails.

Comment: But its not all just emailaddresses I want to store, also the customers telephone number, dateOfBirth and so on.

Comment: Fields that are common to a large proportion of rows should have a field in the main 'Customers' table, or possibly a single extra table like 'CustomersExtraInfo'.  Data that is only applicable to a small number of rows would be a good fit for a dedicated table.

Comment: now there is the problem, I have a lot of data that is only applicable to a small number of rows. I know that moving it to a deticated table is a good fit, but that would mean I end up with 20 tables containing only few data and having each of these tables queried before producing a result.

Comment: If you frequently need to query ALL the fields at once, you're better off with a single table even if most fields are empty.  You could design an EAV (Entity Attribute Value) system to store the data, but this means you'll be unable to seriously optimize rerieval speed.